# How to get Gdk window from xid?

Tags: python-3.x, xlib, gtk3

I'm lost in version 3.. in python2+gdk2 is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import gtk

gtk.gdk.window_process_all_updates()
window_xid = 54525964
gdk_window = gtk.gdk.window_foreign_new(window_xid)
```

which is pretty much straight forward. But then, the horror:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from gi.repository import xlib
from gi.repository import Gdk
from gi.repository import GdkX11

Gdk.Window.process_all_updates()
xlib_window = "???????"
gdk_display = GdkX11.X11Display.get_default()
gdk_window = GdkX11.X11Window.foreign_new_for_display(gdk_display, xlib_window)
```

the xlib is killing me.. I'm unable to do anything with it. Has anybody worked with it before??

The documentation I've through several times already is:
[Gdk3](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/3.0/gdk3-X-Window-System-Interaction.html#gdk-x11-window-foreign-new-for-display),
[Xlib](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/)

Getting the window from its xid was the fastest way to get a screenshot in python2 I guess I'll have try another way in python3.. any ideas? maybe peek_children from root window?? but then, how do I know if it's the window I want?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `Window` in X11 is the same as an `XID`. There's just a typedef from one to the other.

So in C code `gdk_x11_window_foreign_new_for_display()` just accepts an `Window` or `XID`, which is basically an integer. This also works in python using introspection:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from gi.repository import Gdk
from gi.repository import GdkX11

Gdk.Window.process_all_updates()
xlib_window = 0x2a00005 # from xwininfo command
gdk_display = GdkX11.X11Display.get_default()
gdk_window = GdkX11.X11Window.foreign_new_for_display(gdk_display, xlib_window)
print(gdk_window.get_geometry())
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. When I first tried this I think they didn't have it implemented yet.. Just a minor change for python3 though, the `print()` directive now needs parenthesis. Aside from that it works like a charm. Thanks again!