# Get GDK Window from xid, under Wayland

Tags: python, wayland, gobject-introspection

*In a nutshell: this is a repeat of [How to get Gdk window from xid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6850698/798223), but under Wayland.*

Code like the following worked fine until I updated Debian from Stretch to Buster:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from gi.repository import Gdk
from gi.repository import GdkX11

Gdk.Window.process_all_updates()
xlib_window = 0x2a00005 # for example. From wmctrl; xwininfo used in the previous question.
gdk_display = GdkX11.X11Display.get_default()
gdk_window = GdkX11.X11Window.foreign_new_for_display(gdk_display, xlib_window)
print gdk_window.get_geometry()
```

Unfortunately, `gdk_display` is now a `__gi__.GdkWaylandDisplay`, so `GdkX11.X11Window.foreign_new_for_display` throws

```
TypeError: argument display: Expected GdkX11.X11Display, but got __gi__.GdkWaylandDisplay
```

So how do I get my `gdkWindow` now? (I couldn't see the necessary docs online at all, so pointers to then would also be appreciated.)

I'm happy to also get the `gdkWindow` from PID or process name, since that's where I get the XID from.

Comment: What are you using instead of the X window id?

Comment: @JoshLee wmctrl -l is still giving me an int that looks like an xid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general answer, judging by your "for example. From wmctrl" comment, there is no solution.

By design, Wayland doesn't allows applications to meddle with or inspect each other's windows for security reasons.

X11 applications like wmctrl run inside a compatibility layer named XWayland and don't have permission to meddle with native Wayland applications.

You're getting that error because you're trying to use `GdkX11` inside an application that started up as a native Wayland application and it's not fundamentally different from the error you'd get from trying to call Win32 APIs in a C# application that's running natively on Linux.

The only way to make it work is to either look up how to force any relevant applications to fall back to running via XWayland or write whatever you're trying to accomplish as a patch for the Wayland compositor itself.

Comment: Thanks. That's a pain, but I guess it does make sense for Wayland to be preventing processes from meddling with each other.